# Kotlin start Application crash

Tags: android, kotlin

my application is built with kotlin,here is my build.gradle file:

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

and my workspace's build.gradle file:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
ext.kotlin_plugin_version = '1.1.1'
dependencies {
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.4.0"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_plugin_version"
}
```

in my project,I already use java8 with jack, so the gradle-plugin version can only be 1.1.1

when I start my application, it crashes randomly,here is the log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                
Process: com.ss.android.caijing.stock.debug, PID: 31962                                                                                 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;                                                                                      
   at com.ss.android.caijing.stock.main.MainActivity.initData(MainActivity.kt:33)                                                                                      
   at com.ss.android.caijing.stock.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:25)                                                                                      
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6367)                                                                                      
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)                                                                                      
   at com.bytedance.frameworks.plugin.hook.InstrumentationHook$PluginInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(InstrumentationHook.java:248)                                                                                      
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)                                                                                      
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2511)                                                                                      
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:165)                                                                                      
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1375)                                                                                      
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                                      
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)                                                                                      
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5621)                                                                                      
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                      
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)                                                                                      
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)                                                                                      
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ss.android.caijing.stock.debug-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ss.android.caijing.stock.debug-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.ss.android.caijing.stock.debug-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]                                                                                      
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)                                                                                      
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)                                                                                      
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)                                                                                      
   at com.ss.android.caijing.stock.main.MainActivity.initData(MainActivity.kt:33)                                                                                       
   at com.ss.android.caijing.stock.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:25)                                                                                       
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6367)                                                                                       
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)                                                                                       
   at com.bytedance.frameworks.plugin.hook.InstrumentationHook$PluginInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(InstrumentationHook.java:248)                                                                                       
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)                                                                                       
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2511)                                                                                       
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:165)                                                                                       
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1375)                                                                                       
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                                       
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)                                                                                       
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5621)                                                                                       
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                       
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)                                                                                       
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)                                                                                 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics not found                                                                                      
   at com.bytedance.frameworks.plugin.core.DelegateClassLoader.findClass(DelegateClassLoader.java:137)                                                                                      
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)                                                                                      
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)                                                                                                         
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics                                                                                      
   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)                                                                                      
   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)                                                                                      
   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)                                                                                      
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)                                                                                                          
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available                                                                                      
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException                                                                                      
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                      
   at com.bytedance.frameworks.plugin.core.DelegateClassLoader.findClass(DelegateClassLoader.java:60)                                                                                                            
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ss.android.caijing.stock.debug-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ss.android.caijing.stock.debug-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.ss.android.caijing.stock.debug-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]                                                                                      
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)


 private var mPagerAdapter: MainFragmentAdapter? = null
```

override

```
fun initData() { mPagerAdapter = MainFragmentAdapter(supportFragmentManager, this) }
```

the crash happens in the init of the mPageAdapter, the constructor of the MainFragmentPagerAdapter is below:

```
class MainFragmentAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter { private val mContext:     Context constructor(fm: FragmentManager, context: Context) : super(fm) { mContext = context }
```

can somebody help me out,thx a lot!

Comment: Can you please post `MainActivity.kt` code. Which help us to get idea about issue.

Comment: no problem,here is main code of the mainactivity.kt :
`private var mPagerAdapter: MainFragmentAdapter? = null  
 override fun initData() {
        mPagerAdapter = MainFragmentAdapter(supportFragmentManager, this)
    } `

the crash happens in the init of the mPageAdapter, the constructor of the MainFragmentPagerAdapter is below:
`class MainFragmentAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private val mContext: Context

    constructor(fm: FragmentManager, context: Context) : super(fm) {
        mContext = context
    }`

Comment: Ttry to add this dependency: `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"`

Comment: appreciated, but it doesn't work as expected......

Answer (score 5):

Adding the following as an app-level dependency fixed it for me:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
```

--- EDIT ---

This has now been superseded by:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

Comment: $kotlin_version should be like 1.2.50

Answer (score 0):

Add below two line in your app gradle and sync your project.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: "kotlin-android-extensions"
```

It might be having problem to configure kotlin plugin in your android studio.If you still having the same issue than please refer below link It's might be helpfull.

[Setup tutorial 1](https://segunfamisa.com/posts/setting-up-android-studio-for-kotlin-development)

[Setup tutorial 2](https://android.jlelse.eu/setup-kotlin-for-android-studio-1bffdf1362e8)

**Best of Luck**

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work, thx anyway, but I've used multi dex in my application, I don't know if multidex would cause this issue?